# Converting a String to an Integer so that the number values can be added

Tags: string, swift, parse-platform, integer

Hi in the app I am creating I have a points system so that every time the user completes a certain task they are given 100 points.  My problem is that since the object is a string the number values are literally added together so that 100 + 100 comes out as 100100. How do I fix this issue? For some reason .toInt isn't working.

here is my code:

```
 // Give the User Points

    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

        currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (foundUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            // Get and update score

            if (foundUser != nil) {

                let score = foundUser!["score"] as! String

                let points = (("100".toInt())! + (score.toInt())!)

                foundUser!["score"] = points


                foundUser?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if succeeded {

                        println("score added to user")

                    }


                })

            }

        })

    }
```

Another issue is that when the user first starts getting points the column in Parse.com is nil so there is nothing to add the 100 points to so the app crashes.  What do I do about this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Also to solve your second problem, optionally unwrap score and then use any of the ways to deal with optionals in swift. I would recommend the nil coalescing operator `??` so `score ?? 0` says "if score is nil, use 0 instead"

Comment: Also,  `if (foundUser != nil) {` could be better replaced by `if let user = foundUser {` and then use `user` in the block. This allows you to not have to constantly unwrap foundUser in the if block.

Comment: `(("100".toInt())!` is a complicated method to get `100`.

Comment: @Will M. for some reason the .toInt() isn't allowing the string to add together as an Integer

Comment: what does score look like when you get it back?

Comment: It looks like "100100100100" or as many time as 100 has been added together.

Comment: `let score = foundUser!["score"] as! String` what is it after this line?

Comment: This is what the break point says :points Int 6171216376

Comment: Should I change the column for score in Parse to an Number and try saving the score as an Integer instead of a String?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6 or 7? Swift 2, which comes with Xcode 7 replaced "string".toInt() with a string initializer for the Int type. For example Int("100")

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for your scenario?

```
if let  score = foundUser!["score"] as? String {
    if let points = score.toInt() {
        points += 100
        foundUser!["score"] = "\(points)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it does since I am trying to add 100 points to the current score.

Comment: Sure, you read the current score to `score` as string. Then you convert it to int (variable `points`). Then you add 100 to `points`. And finally, you make a string from `points`  again (`"\(points)"`) and write it back to `foundUser!["score"]`

Comment: Ok I got confused by the +=.  For some reason the new score isn't saving to Parse though.